# How do I access Typescript Enum by ordinal

Tags: typescript

I have the following...

```
enum NubDirection {
  OUTWARD,
  INWARD
}
...
direction : NubDirection;
...
let index = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) + 1;
nub.direction = NubDirection[index];
```

But this throws

> error TS2322: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'NubDirection'.

Comment: what is `nub`, missing information.

Comment: Should be obvious but I will add it...

Comment: it is now, wasn't before the first edit

Comment: Ok sorry about that typo

Comment: This  would work, definitely a dirty fix - `Object.keys(NubDirection).indexOf(NubDirection[index]) - (Object.keys(NubDirection).length / 2)`

Answer (score 34, accepted):

When you declare that something is of type `NubDirection` then it's actually a number:

```
var a = NubDirection.INWARD;
console.log(a === 1); // true
```

When you access the enum using the ordinal you get back a string and not a number and because of that you can not assign it to something that was declared as `NubDirection`.

You can do:

```
nub.direction = NubDirection[NubDirection[index]];
```

The reason for this is that there's no such thing as enum in javascript, and the way typescript imitates enums is by doing this when compiling it to js:

```
var NubDirection;
(function (NubDirection) {
    NubDirection[NubDirection["OUTWARD"] = 0] = "OUTWARD";
    NubDirection[NubDirection["INWARD"] = 1] = "INWARD";
})(NubDirection || (NubDirection = {}));
```

So you end up with this object:

```
NubDirection[0] = "OUTWARD";
NubDirection[1] = "INWARD";
NubDirection["OUTWARD"] = 0;
NubDirection["INWARD"] = 1;
```

Comment: @AntonPegov what doesn't work? Seems the same to me

Comment: ErrorCode[Object.keys(ErrorCode)[1]] - works, 
ErrorCode[ErrorCode[1]] - doesn't work

Comment: @AntonPegov I'm not sure what is this `ErrorCode` object you use, but using the example of the OP, this: `NubDirection[NubDirection[1]]` works.

Comment: Oh, yes, but if you set INWARD = 'INWARD' in enum, it is stops work. Strange behavior...

Comment: @AntonPegov Oh, yeah, enums with string values work completely different. Compare the js output of the two and see what the compiler is doing there.

Comment: `nub.direction = NubDirection[NubDirection[index]];` is giving an issue with TypeScript

Answer (score 53):

If you have string enum like so:

```
export enum LookingForEnum {
    Romantic = 'Romantic relationship',
    Casual = 'Casual relationship',
    Friends = 'Friends',
    Fun = 'Fun things to do!'
}
```

Then

```
 const index: number = Object.keys(LookingForEnum).indexOf('Casual'); // 1
```

Comment: What about if you only have the string "Casual relationship", could you still find the index?

Comment: It turns out you can do `Object.values(LookingForEnum).indexOf('Casual relationship')`

Comment: Gotta love the beauty of typescript *sarcastic grin*.

Answer (score 23):

Use this:

```
Object.values(NubDirection)[index]
```

Comment: I just wrote a pipe for my purposes using this method.
It takes in the enum object and then expects an index and returns the string value.


`import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'valueByOrdinal',
})
export class ValueByOrdinalPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(type: any, index): unknown {
    return Object.values(type)[index];
  }
}`

Answer (score 15):

you may use:

```
export enum SpaceCargoShipNames {
  Gnat = 'Gnat',
  Orilla = 'Orilla',
  Ambassador = 'Ambassador',
  CarnarvonBay = 'Carnarvon Bay'
}
```

and then:

```
let max = Object.keys(SpaceCargoShipNames).length;  //items count
let n = Math.round(Math.random() * max);            //random index
let v = Object.values(SpaceCargoShipNames)[n];      //item
console.log(max, n, v, v.valueOf());
```

Answer (score 6):

None of the answers above quite did it for me. What you can do is something like:

```
// Do whatever math operation with an index you wish...
...

// Get the the enum string value:
const nextStringedEnum: string = Object.values(NubDirection)[nextIndex];

// Get the typed enum from the string value:
const nextIndex: NubDirection = Object.values(NubDirection).indexOf(nextStringedEnum);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also access like this.

## enum values

```
export enum TEST_ENUM {
 T1 = "This is test 1"
 T2 = "This is test 2"
}
```

## Component

```
var a: string = "T1";
let b = (TEST_ENUM as any)[a];

console.log("val b: ", b);     // This is test 1
```

or

```
let c = Object.keys(TEST_ENUM).indexOf(a);

console.log("val c: ", c);     // This is test 1
```

Comment: I'd change type of `a` from `string` to `keyof typeof TEST_ENUM`. And I'm not really understand idea of acessing enum via string instead of just TEST_ENUM.T1

Comment: @Tomas You're right I'm just showing this way would also work.

Answer (score 0):

Because of confusion with string enums and their blurry nature and issues with ordinal accessing, I prefer to rather use numerical enums and pretend them to be  string ones:

```
enum StringEnum {
    STRING_ONE = 0,
    STRING_TWO
}

console.log(StringEnum.STRING_ONE)
console.log(StringEnum[StringEnum.STRING_ONE])
```

this will give you

```
[LOG]: 0 
[LOG]: "STRING_ONE"
```

And you can have best of both worlds: significant string labeling that is easy accessible without using any `indexOf` search and explicit numerical values.

Just by previewing compilation output it's obvious, that usage of numerical enums is more reach in options:

```
enum StringEnum {
    STRING_ONE = 'string1',
    STRING_TWO = 'string2'
}
```

gives

```
"use strict";
var StringEnum;
(function (StringEnum) {
    StringEnum["STRING_ONE"] = "string1";
    StringEnum["STRING_TWO"] = "string2";
})(StringEnum || (StringEnum = {}));
```

while

```
enum StringEnum {
    STRING_ONE = 0,
    STRING_TWO
}
```

immediately enables both possibilities:

```
"use strict";
var StringEnum;
(function (StringEnum) {
    StringEnum[StringEnum["STRING_ONE"] = 0] = "STRING_ONE";
    StringEnum[StringEnum["STRING_TWO"] = 1] = "STRING_TWO";
})(StringEnum || (StringEnum = {}));
```

If you need even further explicit string mapping, i.e. whole user prompts or so, I;m usually hanlding this by additional mapping table:

```
enum StringEnum {
    STRING_ONE = 0,
    STRING_TWO
}

export type EnumMapper = {
    someExtendedText: string,
    ENUM_KEY: keyof typeof StringEnum
}

const mapper: EnumMapper[] = [
    {someExtendedText: 'Some long bla bla bla', ENUM_KEY: "STRING_ONE"},
    {someExtendedText: 'Some other long bla bla', ENUM_KEY: "STRING_TWO"}
]

let desriptionForEnumOne = mapper[StringEnum.STRING_ONE].someExtendedText;
```