# Get index of enum value typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I have the following string enum:

```
export enum RecordStatus {
   ONGOING_ADMINISTRATIVE_ANALYSIS = 'ONGOING_ADMINISTRATIVE_ANALYSIS',

   ONGOING_TECHNICAL_ANALYSIS = 'ONGOING_TECHNICAL_ANALYSIS',

   COMPLETED_APPLICATION = 'COMPLETED_APPLICATION'
}
```

I have the following function:

```
setTimelineStatus(status: RecordStatus) : void {
    console.log("State :" + status); // ON_GOING_TECHNICAL_ANALYSIS

    console.log(RecordStatus.valueOf(status).ordinal()); // doesn't work. Should print 1

    console.log(RecordStatus.valueOf("ON_GOING_TECHNICAL_ANALYSIS").ordinal()); // doesn't work either. Should print 1
}
```

This function retrieves a set enum as parameter, for example `RecordStatus.ON_GOING_TECHNICAL_ANALYSIS`. I want to get the index (it should be 1 in above case). I tried the solution in this thread [Get index of enum from string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15436721/get-index-of-enum-from-string) but I've got this error:

[image: Error]

I don't understand why I have this error. I only want the index of the enum value.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I access Typescript Enum by ordinal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39427542/how-do-i-access-typescript-enum-by-ordinal)

Comment: could you try `status.valueOf()`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The post you are refering to is for enums in Java.

In TypeScript, **enum** are considered **objects** at runtime so *you can just iterate over the keys of the enum until you find the one you're looking for*.

```
Object.keys(RecordStatus).indexOf('ON_GOING_TECHNICAL_ANALYSIS');
```

Comment: I didn't see it was Java! It works with `console.log(Object.keys(RecordStatus).indexOf(status));` (the parameter), however when I try with your suggestion I get -1. But it doesn't matter, I have the solution, thanks!

Comment: @HéloïseChauvel the reason you are getting `-1` is because it is incorrectly spelled. It should be `ONGOING_TECHNICAL_ANALYSIS` (note the `_` that is removed after `ON`), based on your enum stated above.

Answer (score 2):

This code returns the index of enum item. Besides it TypeScript-guarded, i.e. would not allow to make a mistake in the enum item identifier, provided your IDE supports TypeScript:

```js
Object.values(RecordStatus).indexOf(RecordStatus.ONGOING_ADMINISTRATIVE_ANALYSIS)
```